# Mesh deforming when armature is moved

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

My character's leg is deforming when the master bone of the armature, or any bone, moves away from the default position. It always points there, and I believe it may be because of the object's origin.I have made sure everything is weight painted already. Here is a screenshot : http://gyazo.com/498f419cb9334c5a052cbaa977b4452c

You can view the blend file here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/8k380bhhhzmzgod/PROBLEM.blend?dl=0

Any ideas? I'm relatively new to blender.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bone on different layer which has influence on the legs :

- select the bone in the outliner
- switch it to layer 1
- go to weight paint for the legs and clean the weight

[image]